# SpaCy 3.2.1, How to add new entitie without losing the default ones

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am trying to add new entities to the already existing model en_core_web_lg. If I don't train the model recognize all the entities. In the moment that I train it, it seems to forget all the previous entities. Can someone help me please? Here's the code:

```
def main(new_model_name=new_model_name, output_dir=output_dir, n_iter=n_iter):
print("\n")
# Load pre-existing spacy model
nlp=spacy.load(output_dir)

# Getting the pipeline component
if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
    nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

# Adding labels to the `ner`
for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
    for ent in annotations.get("entities"):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])

# Disable pipeline components you dont need to change
disabled_pipes = []
for pipe_name in nlp.pipe_names:
    if pipe_name != 'ner':
        nlp.disable_pipes(pipe_name)
        disabled_pipes.append(pipe_name)

# TRAINING THE MODEL
optimizer = nlp.create_optimizer()
for iteration in range(n_iter):
        # Shuffling examples  before every iteration
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}

        # Batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
        for batch in spacy.util.minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001)):
            for text, annotations in batch:
                # create Example
                doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
                example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
                # Update the model
                nlp.update([example], sgd=optimizer,losses=losses, drop=0.8)

        print(f"{iteration+1}/{n_iter} - Losses {losses}")

for pipe_name in disabled_pipes:
    nlp.enable_pipe(pipe_name)

print("\n")
if output_dir is not None:
    # Save the  model to directory
    nlp.meta["name"] = new_model_name  
    nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
    print(colored(f"Saved model to {output_dir}", 'white'))

    # Load the saved model and predict      
    print(colored(f"Loading from {output_dir}", 'white'))
    nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
    for text, _ in TEST_DATA:
        doc = nlp2(text)
        print("Entities", [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
        print("Tokens", [(t.text, t.ent_type_, t.ent_iob) for t in doc])
```

Comment: Please see the spaCy FAQ https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226#:~:text=My%20retrained%20model%20forgot%20pretrained%20entities